# Is it possible to draw a percentage stacked barplot when you only have samples+variable percentages?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
df <- data.frame(sd = c('05AP.U1 1 ','05AP.U2 1','07RT.U1 1'),percentpl = c(50,40,80),percentan = c(50,60,20),count = c(100,100,100))

sd        percentpl  percentan  count
1  05AP.U1       50        50   100
9  03KM.U2       40        60   100 
12 07RT.U1       80        20   100
```

Is it possiple to draw a stacked,percent barplot onlyon the base of `df`. I tried it with `ggplot` but failed on the `fill` variable.

```
ggplot(df, aes(fill=`percentpl`+`percentan`, y=count, x=`sd`)) + 
    geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity")+ theme(axis.text = element_text(angle = 90))
```

I have seen couple of other similar questions [R ggplot2 stacked barplot, percent on y axis, counts in bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51215221/r-ggplot2-stacked-barplot-percent-on-y-axis-counts-in-bars)    [Add percentage labels to a stacked barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724580/add-percentage-labels-to-a-stacked-barplot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for this. As your `count` variable adds to 100 because of values in `percentpl` and  `percentan` you can reshape based on those variables and obtain the filled plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
#Data
df <- data.frame(sd = c('05AP.U1 1 ','05AP.U2 1','07RT.U1 1'),
                 percentpl = c(50,40,80),
                 percentan = c(50,60,20),
                 count = c(100,100,100))
#Melt and plot
df %>% select(-count) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -sd) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=sd,y=value,fill=name)) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity")+
  theme(axis.text = element_text(angle = 90))
```

Output:

[image]